# Laravel Eloquent: referential integrity with delete

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: beerglasses, tags and beerglasses_tags. One beerglass can have multiple tags.

```
    Schema::create('beerglasses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('brewery_id');
        $table->foreign( 'brewery_id' )
            ->references( 'id' )->on( 'breweries' )
            ->onUpdate( 'cascade' )
            ->onDelete( 'cascade' );
        $table->string('beerglass_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('beerglasses_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('beerglass_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('beerglass_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('beerglasses')
                ->onUpdate( 'cascade' )
                ->onDelete( 'cascade' );
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('tags')
                ->onUpdate( 'cascade' )
                ->onDelete( 'cascade' );
    });

    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');            
        $table->string('tag_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have the following entries:

```
mysql> select id, brewery_id, beerglass_name from beerglasses;
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | brewery_id | beerglass_name |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  4 |          3 | Glass1         |
|  5 |          3 | Glass2         |
+----+------------+----------------+

mysql> select * from beerglasses_tag;
+----+--------------+--------+
| id | beerglass_id | tag_id |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  3 |            4 |      4 |
|  4 |            5 |      3 |
+----+--------------+--------+

 mysql> select id, tag_name from tags;
+----+----------+
| id | tag_name |
+----+----------+
|  3 | Tag 1    |
|  4 | Tag 2    |
```

The behaviour is such that I can't delete 'beerglasses' because there are tags associated to it. E.g. if I want to delete beerglass 4, it complains that it can't delete it. Guess this is because beerglass 4 is associated to tag 4.

At all times, I want to be able to delete 'beerglasses'. If the beerglass references tags, it should delete the reference from the beerglasses_tag table.

Then next, I would only like to delete 'tags' if they are not used by any beerglasses in the database.

How do I have to change the Schema to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use eloquent model relation? Can you provide your Model schemes? 
If, you did, then you need to empty/delete the associated tags before deleting the beerglass.

```
$beerglass->tags->detach()
$beerglass->delete();
```

and vice-versa. Because, in many to many relationship, when you delete an item, then the related items will still look up for that deleted item and that may create a problem. So, before deleting an item , we need to clear up the related items from the pivot table. In your case, you need to make sure you have cleared the pivot table's entry linking with the 'Beerglass' before deleting.

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. I thought that SQL would automatically take care of removing the entry in the pivot table. Indeed, detaching the tags in the application code is working as per your suggestion.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks